# Algolia autosuggest library generating postmessage with invalid data (twitter typeahead)

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, typeahead.js, postmessage, algolia

We're using the Algolia autocomplete module with our React application. We noticed that this autocomplete library is using postmessage to send messages.

The messages that the library is sending appear to have data that throw an exception if JSON.parse is called on the message data.

We have a requirement that our React module not be posting messages with data that does not pass JSON.parse.

We've seen messages that have empty data and other messages with data that starts with the string 'setImmediate$'. We need to subdue these messages.

Why is the autosuggest library generating these postmessages? 
Is there a way that we can stop these postmessages from being sent?

Thank you,
Brian

Comment: That's weird, I would recommend investigating the JSON answer that Algolia answers to confirm there is a JSON parsing issue. And probably to reach out to support@algolia.com to get more help!

Answer (score 0):

a fix was released for autocomplete.js: https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js/pull/146

Let me know if it works for you!